# DataGridView with Checkbox saving an ID instead of just a TRUE FALSE

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview, tabular

I'm using **vb.net**,
and I'm having little bit exp 
for using **datagridview** as my tabular
interface.

And now, I just wondering
what should I do to make a custom datagridview?

Because I want to try make like this 
DatagridView as a table;

```
[Checkbox] - [Name]
```

from my Database:

```
[ID] - [Name]
```

how could I store this ID data into the 
Checkbox render on the DataGridView?
So instead of TRUE FALSE, I wanted to save
the ID if TRUE, and I don't save if it's FALSE.

How could I make it ?

Comment: 2 columns in your DB (ID and Name) are related to 3 columns in your DGV (ID, checkbox and Name); and you want to store the ID/Name cells from the DGV into the DB, only if the corresponding checkboxes are checked? Am I am right? Also, could you please post the code you have tried?

Comment: last time I tried to implement a TRUE value for the ID. and the false value for the FALSE. Thus, i tried to checked whether the Checkbox has been selected or not by the CHECKED Value.

Comment: You are kind of slow in replying, aren't you? I was pretty clear in my comment above: post your code (with "could you please" I meant "please, do it") to understand exactly your problem and to show us what you have tried  (we are not writing codes for anyone requesting them; for this you have software developers you can hire). Please take a look at the help pages to understand how SO should be used and remember that this is not just about you, but also about future readers. This question as it is right now is off-topic.